# Como criar uma biblioteca para som?

Tags: android, armazenamento

Na minha aplicação é gravado o som normalmente, só que eu queria renomear o som gravado e logo em seguida armazenar no dispositivo.

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/javacodegeeksRecording.3gpp";

myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
myRecorder.setAudioSource (MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
myRecorder.setOutputFormat (MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
myRecorder.setAudioEncoder (MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
myRecorder.setOutputFile (outputFile);
```

```
 public void start(View view){ // começar a gravar
        try {
            myRecorder.prepare();
            myRecorder.start();

            //imglisten.setEnabled(false);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // start:it is called before prepare()
            // prepare: it is called after start() or before setOutputFormat()
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // prepare() fails
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stop(View view){ //para de gravar
        try {
            myRecorder.stop();
            myRecorder.release();
            myRecorder  = null;

            //imglisten.setEnabled(true);

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            //  it is called before start()
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // no valid audio/video data has been received
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Eu queria que logo após para de gravar(*stop*), o botão salvar pudesse renomear o som gravado e armazenado. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu ficheiro de *audio* foi gravado no caminho passado ao método `myRecorder.setOutputFile();`:

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                          "/javacodegeeksRecording.3gpp";
....
....
myRecorder.setOutputFile (outputFile);
```

Para renomear esse ficheiro use o método [renameTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) da classe *File*:

```
//Criar um objecto File com o caminho actual
File actualAudio = new File(outputFile);

//Caminho com o novo nome
String novoNome = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                              "/novo_nome.3gpp";

//Criar um objecto File com o caminho novo
File novoAudio = new File(novoNome);

//Fazer o rename
boolean sucesso = actualAudio.renameTo(novoAudio);
```

Comment: tenho 2 perguntas:
1 - Como eu poderia fazer para quando o usuário clicar em salvar, abrir uma janela e dai ele poder renomear o arquivo e poder armazenar no dispositivo?
2 - Todo os arquivos gravados já estão sendo armazenados no dispositivo ? caso não esteja, como eu poderia colocar para salvar no dispositivo?

Comment: Os arquivos são logo armazenados. Se você quer perguntar ao usuário qual o nome do arquivo faça isso antes de começar a gravar. Em vez de `outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                          "/javacodegeeksRecording.3gpp";` abra um *dialog* para perguntar e passe a resposta no método `myRecorder.setOutputFile(resposta_do_utilizador)`. Nesse caso não é necessário fazer o *rename*. Pesquise sobre como fazer *Dialogs*. Se tiver alguma dificuldade poste uma nova pergunta.

Comment: consegui fazer o dialog, então nessa parte do código File novoAudio = new File(novoNome); ele já substitui o velho? e também não entendi essa parte aqui  boolean sucesso = actualAudio.renameTo(novoAudio);

Comment: A linha que faz o *rename* é `boolean sucesso = actualAudio.renameTo(novoAudio); `